# Адаптация grid элементов

Tags: javascript, html, css

как адаптируется грид фотографий на этом сайте https://unsplash.com/ с помощью js.
Возможно они как-то сортируются 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Что бы такое сделать не обязательно использовать JS[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это делается по колонкам отдельными слоями, то есть при определенной ширине - 3 колонки. При другой - 2 и так далее, регулируется max-width. Так же можно реализовать все на флексе - 32% от ширины при flex-direction: space-beetwen. Дальше регулировать max-width...